# Using StackTrace-js .get method slow down the performance

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resolve stacktrace using:

[Stacktrace-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stacktrace-js)

I am new to JS in general and to stack trace, I am using the get method:

```
StackTrace.get(options ).then(callback)
```

of course callback is a defined callback function while options contains sourCache and offline=true

My problem is when I use

> .get(options)

and when the sourceCache is not an empty object (not {}) the website becomes slow and there is more memory consumption (recognized form web developer tools)

I searched and I didn't find a mention for such a problem and I am pretty sure that the slowness is not from my callback function.. so what is the problem ?

Also in the documentation of the stacktrace-js the mentioned:

> Pre-populate source cache to avoid network requests

What does this sentence exactly mean ?

Comment: Did you find any answers to this?  In particular to the "Pre-populate source cache" issue?

Comment: actually not :/ and now I am in a new problem regarding caught exception when I call .get method